# F# - Function like List.find but search for any of a Dictionary's keys

Tags: f#

I want to create an F# function like List.find, but instead of searching for a single value, I want to search for any of the keys of a dictionary and return the corresponding dictionary value. 
For example, this is a (poor) implementation of what I am trying to do.

```
let dict1=dict[(1,"A");(2,"B");(3,"C");(4,"D");(5,"E");(6,"F")]

let findInDict l = 
    let mutable found=false
    let mutable value=""
    for elem in l do
        let f,v=dict1.TryGetValue(elem)
        value<-if f && not found then v else value
        found<-if not found then f else found
    value

findInDict [9;2;5]


> 

val dict1 : System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int,string>
val findInDict : l:seq<int> -> string
val it : string = "B"
```

What would be a functional equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function for this almost feels like overkill.  You can do this in one line using a list comprehension:

```
[for x in [9;4;5] do if dict1.ContainsKey x then yield dict1.[x]]
```

Edit:

After re-reading your question, I realized the above was not quite what you are looking for.

```
let rec findAValue l =
    match l with
    | [] -> None
    | x::xs -> if dict1.ContainsKey x then Some(dict1.[x]) else findAValue xs
```

or more succinctly:

```
let rec findAValue = function 
           | [] -> None
           | x::xs -> if dict1.ContainsKey x then Some(dict1.[x]) else findAValue xs
```

even more succinctly:

```
let findAValue = List.tryPick (fun x-> if dict1.ContainsKey x then Some(dict1.[x]) else None)

let highPerformanceFindAValue = List.tryPick (fun x-> match dict1.TryGetValue x with 
                                                      | true, value->Some(value) 
                                                      | _ -> None)
```

In the case where no value is found the result is `None` otherwise it's `Some(value)`.

Comment: tryPick is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Feel dumb for overlooking this function.

Comment: @user3058579 it appears the other answerers did as well. ;-)

Comment: FYI - the last solution accesses the dictionary twice per successful key.  Better to use TryGetValue().

Comment: @plinth They all do, but that's only an issue if performance is important.

Comment: @plinth I added a version with `TryGetValue` in case anyone cares.

Comment: Nice.  Also - tryPick always returns a single option value - do you want the first hit or all?  Finally, better to use Seq in general as it works on lists, arrays, and sequences expressions, whereas the List functions will only work on, well, lists. (honestly, not hating on your answers, just trying to get to 'better').

Comment: @plinth That actually doesn't work.  If you use `Seq` instead of `List`, the parameter type can't be inferred. `let findAValue = Seq.tryPick (fun x-> if dict1.ContainsKey x then Some(dict1.[x]) else None)` is a value restriction error.  I supposed I could do `let findAValue l = Seq.tryPick (fun x-> if dict1.ContainsKey x then Some(dict1.[x]) else None) l` but that's less pretty :-P .

Answer (score 1):

```
let findFirst l (dict: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>) = 
    let o = l |> List.tryFind (fun i -> dict.ContainsKey(i)) |> Option.map (fun k -> dict.[k])
    match o with | None -> "" | Some(k) -> k
```

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of ways to do this.

The obvious solution is to iterate, like you did:

```
let findInDict (d:IDictionary<'a, 'b>) l =
    seq {
        for key in l do
            let f, v = d.TryGetValue(key)
            if f then yield v
    }
```

which is OK, I guess.  It more or less mimics the typical step-wise approach.

You could rewrite this in terms of some sequence operators:

```
let findInDict1 (d:IDictionary<'a, 'b>) l =
    Seq.filter (fun elem -> d.ContainsKey(elem)) l |> Seq.map (fun elem -> d.Item(elem))
```

which feels more functional, but is clearly doing way more work than it should be.

```
let findInDict2 (d:IDictionary<'a, 'b>) l =
    Seq.choose(fun elem ->
        let f,v = d.TryGetValue(elem)
        if f then Some(v) else None) l
```

The last one makes the most sense in that we're only ever accessing the dictionary once per key and choose will do all the heavy lifting for us under the hood.